# Is there a replacement for Gedcom in the works?

Tags: standards, gedcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are genealogical data standards futures currently being discussed/developed?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/where-are-genealogical-data-standards-futures-currently-being-discussed-develope)

Right now there are many data formats (many commercial and open source programs have their own) and GEDCOM is the de facto standard for interworking. It has many deficiencies. Is there work underway to come up with a replacement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where are genealogical data standards futures currently being discussed/developed?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/1448/where-are-genealogical-data-standards-futures-currently-being-discussed-develope) which itself is a duplicate of http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/25/what-standards-exist-for-the-exchange-of-genealogical-information

Comment: Not a duplicate of _What standards exist for the exchange of genealogical information?_. Today, the answer to that question is, in one word: GEDCOM. This question asks about GEDCOM replacements.

Answer (score 1):

[Gedcom X](http://www.gedcomx.org/About.html) is a project by [familysearch](https://familysearch.org/). It is being done open-source and anyone can participate. More information can be found [here](http://www.gedcomx.org/Community.html).

The [Family History Information Standards Organisation](http://fhiso.org/) is in the process of being formed to address the standarization of genealogy data and exchange. People or organizations interested in participating can find information [here](http://fhiso.org/membership-enquiries/).

It is not clear is the above efforts will merge or compete.

Comment: GEDCOM X is not being developed as a GEDCOM replacement. It is being developed to allow selected programs to exchange data between themselves and Family Search. It does not appear to be developed to exchange data between programs or persons.

Comment: @Alex as [I stated elsewhere](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/2370/do-any-programs-use-gedcom-x-as-opposed-to-gedcom/2382#comment3207_2373), this is incorrect.

Comment: Any update on how the process fares nowadays?